# How to upload image to server from xamarin forms app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to send an image from my xamarin forms application to a asp .net core server using a post request. I need to save the image in some server folder but I can not do it.

This is the method to send the image once I have it selected in _mediaFile

```
    private async void UploadFile_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.UsersRestUrl + "/Files/Upload/", string.Empty));
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        content.Add(new StreamContent(_mediaFile.GetStream()),
            "\"file\"",
            $"\"{_mediaFile.Path}\"");

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
    }
```

I currently have this in my api controller

```
    [Route("Files/Upload/")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile file)
    {
        Debug.Write("******");
        // full path to file in temp location
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
        Debug.Write("****** File Path " + filePath);

        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
        return Ok(new { file });
    }
```

I tried to apply this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads but it is oriented to save the image directly from an asp net core application.
Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: there must be SOMETHING running on the server that will accept the upload - you can't just arbitrarily upload files to servers

Comment: Yes I know, I have an api controller working. I update the question with my actual method to get the post request.

Comment: What is the full URI that you are trying to use? And what mobile OS are you using?

Comment: google "xamarin image upload site:stackoverflow.com"

Comment: From your question I don't really get what your expectations are and what the actual behavior is. Do you want to pass a folder with the HTTP request or do you want to save your files to a *certain* folder?

Comment: I finally got it. I have posted an answer with what I have done. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I got it! What I needed was to send an image and save it to a server inside wwwroot folder. I leave here the method for server controller in case someone needs it in the future.

```
    [Route("Files/Upload/")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile file)
    {
        //Windows path
        var uploadLocation = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Uploads\\UsersImg");

        //Linux path
        //var uploadLocation = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Uploads//UsersImg");

        var fileName = file.FileName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault().Split('/').LastOrDefault();

        if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadLocation, fileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
        return Ok();
    }
```

The image is saved in /Uploads/UsersImg/ folder inside wwwroot folder.
The method to send the image from client to server it's the same I posted in the question.

If someone can vote up the question to help other users would be fine. Thanks!!!

Comment: How did u upload it thru xamrain side would be helpfull to show a snippet of how u posted it please